# How can I make a request coming from inside of a docker container appear to be coming from my local machine?

Tags: docker, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

A browser running in docker container needs to make a POST to a login service running on a test API in our network. The service is very picky about where POST can come from so it's rejecting the POST because it's coming from `host.docker.internal` instead of `localhost.company.com`.

It's very unlikely I'd be able to get `host.docker.internal` added to the whitelist.

The POST will work fine if the browser is running on my local machine but fails when the browser is running inside a container on my local machine.

I've tried `docker run --add-host='localhost.mycompany.com:127.0.0.1'` and `docker run --add-host='localhost:127.0.0.1'`, neither one worked. The latter seems silly; it was kind of a shot in the dark...

A possible further complication: the browser is running in testcafe inside a Docker container, so my request will have headers like `'Origin: http://172.17.0.2:1337'` `'Referer: http://172.17.0.2:1337/WBrtZV38p/http://host.docker.internal:3000/app/'`

Short of making a proxy of some sort on my local machine, is there a way to make a POST from the docker container appear to be coming from my local machine?

Comment: thers an extension for some browsers that removes the origin header (or stops it from adding it) this might work if its only for testing purposes

Comment: Ive found this one even tohugh I havent used it personally which should do the trick : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start container in the host OS network space with `docker run --network host ...` - container will be running in the network of your local machine directly. But you will lose container network isolation, so you should to review security of this approach.

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: Hmm, that might work but it seems to break my debugging ports `docker run --network='host' --expose 9230 -p 9230:9230 --expose 9222 -p 9222:9222 -e NODE_OPTIONS="--inspect=0.0.0.0:9230"`  -- do you know how to work around that? It didn't fix my test so I need to debug and figure out what the headers look like

Comment: Don't publish (expose) any ports - you are already running in host OS network.

Comment: Right but the test is still failing and I need to debug the browser that's running in the host to sort out what's happening. Chromium allows that with `--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 --remote-debugging-port=9222` but if I can't expose those ports... I thought the node process would show up normally (as in, just like any other node process in debug mode) but it is not

Comment: Publishing of the container ports = forwarding ports from the container network space to the host os network space. But with `--network host` you are already starting container in host OS network space and app are binding host OS network interfaces. So debug on your local host OS interfaces.